# Wordpress creating "Pages" tab on admin panel that only shows specific Pages

Tags: wordpress, admin

I've managed to create a tab in the admin panel of Wordpress using add_menu_page(); Within the function for that menu page, how do I make it so that it shows the pages I want it to, similar to the default Pages tab, except I want to query it to a specific category.

A standard wp_query get posts does not seem to work here. I've tried looking on google for my situation, but either I am poor at describing it, or it is not a common situation.

Comment: Just to understand your problem, you have multiple pages having different categories. And you want to select pages of a specific category to be displayed on your custom tab. The display of your custom tab will be similar to default Pages tab. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Check this: [How do you create a custom edit.php / edit pages page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/115164/12615)